# mongo filter add sort options

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch data for table and currently pagination works fine but I want to fetch data in ascending order. So that on each page order of the data against column `cost.extendedCost` value must be sorted. Here is my query that I am currently sending to backend

```
{"$and":[{"$or":[{"customerId":"jDrTugIeG"},{"primaryCustomerId":"jDrTugIeG"}]}],"meta.requestCount":{"$lte":44232}}
```

I just need the data to be sorted based on this value `{"sort": {"cost.extendedCost": 1}}`. How can I add this sort option to above mongo query?

Comment: Check out [Sort Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/sort/#sort-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 db.collection.find({"$and":[{"$or":[{"customerId":"jDrTugIeG"},{"primaryCustomerId":"jDrTugIeG"}]}],"meta.requestCount":{"$lte":44232}}).sort({"cost.extendedCost": 1})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.